# Predicate pushdown not happening using shc core

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I am actually facing a problem with my HBase table that is evolving every day. I am using ̀ shc core  to read the table as a DataFrame and I am storing every column as `STRING` type. What I am trying to do is to read each day just the last 30 days of data. Given that the table is evolving each day it takes more than 6 hours to load the whole table and then apply the filters.

I am using shc versions 1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11

What am doing is this :

```
val df = withCatalog(catalog)

df.filter($"date > "20191201" && $"date < "20200101")
```

When i do `explain()` it shows me this in the physical plan

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Filter (isnotnull(ip#16) && (ip#16 >= 4F62B402))
+- *Filter <function1>.apply
   +- *Scan HBaseRelation(Map(catalog ->....
```

I don't see `PushedFilters: [...]`which means there is no predicate that was pushed down.

Anyone please can help me on this issue?

**EDIT after shay__ suggestiong**

I added :

```
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
```

And in my yarn logs i got :

> DEBUG HBaseFilter: for all filters:
>
> DEBUG HBaseFilter: ret: DEBUG
>
> HBaseFilter: start: None end: None

This means, based on the code below, there were no filters translated into HbaseFilter therefore no pushed down filters although on the physical plan we can see that a filter does exist.

https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/blob/76673b40b3ce370d0fbc4614938cbe54cfffa082/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/hbase/HBaseFilter.scala#L127

Comment: try to set debug level logging - https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/blob/76673b40b3ce370d0fbc4614938cbe54cfffa082/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/hbase/HBaseFilter.scala#L127

Comment: are you using the correct connector?

Comment: I added the log level to DEBUG mode using
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
And i got the same result. Still can't see any PushedFilters on my physical plan. And yes i am using the correct conenctor.